# Win 11 Registry Edit - Verification/Translators?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

There is a [homebrew registry patch](https://rogallylife.com/2023/08/15/900p-1600x900-resolution-rog-ally/) going around which adds a 1600x900 display setting to the new ROG Ally Handheld PC.

The registry edit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000]
"DALNonStandardModesBCD1"=hex:\
  19,20,10,80,00,00,00,00,\
  16,00,09,00,00,00,00,00,\
  12,80,07,20,00,00,00,00
"DALRestrictedModesBCD1"=hex:\
  51,20,28,80,00,00,00,00,\
  38,40,24,00,00,00,00,00,\
  51,20,21,60,00,00,00,00,\
  38,40,21,60,00,00,00,00,\
  32,00,18,00,00,00,00,00,\
  30,72,17,28,00,00,00,00,\
  38,40,16,20,00,00,00,00,\
  25,60,16,00,00,00,00,00
"DALRestrictedModesBCD2"=hex:\
  20,48,15,36,00,00,00,00,\
  25,60,14,40,00,00,00,00,\
  19,20,12,00,00,00,00,00,\
  16,00,12,00,00,00,00,00,\
  16,80,10,50,00,00,00,00,\
  12,80,10,24,00,00,00,00,\
  16,00,10,00,00,00,00,00,\
  17,60,09,90,00,00,00,00
"DALRestrictedModesBCD3"=hex:\
  12,80,08,00,00,00,00,00,\
  10,24,07,68,00,00,00,00,\
  13,66,07,68,00,00,00,00,\
  11,28,06,34,00,00,00,00,\
  08,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,\
  06,40,04,80,00,00,00,00,\
  08,54,04,80,00,00,00,00
"DALRestrictedModesBCD4"=hex:
"DALRestrictedModesBCD5"=hex:
```

Users in the community don't want to blindly run edits like this (myself included). Does a verification tool exist? Something to at least convert parts of it to human readable text to understand the basis of what it will be changing?

Comment: Off topic for this forum, but I also must wonder: _why_? For desktop use, it's better to use DPI scaling (this gives sharper text and images); in practically all games, you can set the render resolution directly and 1600x900 is already an option.